# Windows form, objects appear infront of other items?

Tags: c#, winforms, krypton

When I add krypton items to my form, they appear over the top of the others, how can I make it so that I can put something behind the other items?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Winform designer, you can right click a control and select 'Bring to Front' or 'Send to Back' from the context menu to change the control's 'z-order.'

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me select it when he answered.

Answer (score 4):

The order of control appearing inside their parrent container is controlled by Z-Index.

Right click control in the designer. Select "Bring ro front" from the context menu.

If you doing it programmtiacly. All control in winforms environment have two methods : BringToFront() and SendToBack(). You can call it to setup z-index of controls.

If you want to specify Z-Index explicitly you may use this workaround:

```
public static class ControlExtension
{

    public static void SetControlZIndex(this Control ctrl, int z)
    {
       ctrl.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(ctrl, z);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
button1.SetControlZIndex(10);
```