# How to set which of the forms appear first

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner c# programmer, and i'm getting familiar with the Windows Forms App.
I have 2 forms and i'm trying to understand how to set one of them to be the first one that appears when i'm running the application.

Is there a way to set this, or I have to create the forms by the order they appears?

Comment: Are you trying to make one appear first or on top? The answer below is good for the being first. Consider z-order for putting one on top of the other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049927/windows-form-objects-appear-infront-of-other-items

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In `Program.cs`, you will see the following line of code

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

This line shows `Form1`.
You can change it to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Program.cs, you will see the following line of code

Application.Run(new Form1());
This line shows Form1.
You can change it to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Write in Program.cs

```
Application.Run(new YourMainForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your visual studi, when ever you open a project by default program.cs will open.

```
   static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

you can see above Application.Run(new Form1());

whatever your form name is type there, then whenever you are starting first this form will run